# Sign_transaction and send_raw_transaction error in Web3.py

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, remix, blockchain, web3.py

I would like to sign_transaction and send raw transaction with custom transaction fields. But I could not do it. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks
[image: web3.py code to sign and send transaction]

[image: read a text file containing transaction details]
[image: error logs]

Answer (score 2):

There are a few issues.

If it's just Python syntax, then you are missing commas and the dictionary for `row`:

```
# Fixed commas and row.id and row.trust_value
for row in addresses_df.itertuples():
    nonce_cnt = int(nonce_count)
    transaction = {
    'to': row.address,
    'value': int(row.balance),
    'gas': 21000,
    'gasPrice': 1000000000,
    'nonce': nonce_cnt,
    'id': row.id,
    'trust value': row.trust_value
    }
```

This might be enough since I don't know what's in the 90 lines of code leading to this.

But in general, `id` & `trust_value` are not a part of an Ethereum transaction, so hypothetically anyone that'd want to add them as a custom field to a transaction, they'd need to encode them and add as `data` to a transaction.

For example, this would work:

```
import os
import time
import pandas as pd
from web3 import Web3

from pathlib import Path
from eth_account.messages import encode_defunct

ganache_url = "http://127.0.0.1:7545"
web3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider(ganache_url))

account_1 = "ADDRESS"
account_2 = "ADDRESS"
private_key = "PRIVATE_KEY"

addresses_df = pd.read_csv(
    'test.txt',
    header=None, names=['id', 'address', 'balance', 'trust_value']
)

# Encode id and trust_value to hex format
def encode_to_hex(id_val, trust_val):
    id_hex = hex(id_val)[2:].rjust(8, '0')
    trust_val_hex = hex(trust_val)[2:].rjust(2, '0')
    return "0x" + id_hex + trust_val_hex

nonce_count = web3.eth.get_transaction_count(account_1)

# Iterate through addresses and send txs with the encoded input in the data field for the tx
for row in addresses_df.itertuples():
    nonce_cnt = int(nonce_count)
    encoded_input = encode_to_hex(row.id, row.trust_value)
    transaction = {
        'to': row.address,
        'value': int(row.balance),
        'gas': 100000, # Change gas from 21k to higher since we are now sending a tx with data, which is higher cost
        'gasPrice': 1000000000,
        'nonce': nonce_cnt,
        'data': encoded_input
    }
    signed = web3.eth.account.sign_transaction(transaction, private_key)
    TxHash = web3.eth.send_raw_transaction(signed.rawTransaction)
    print("Address:", row.address, "Nonce:", nonce_cnt, "TX:", TxHash.hex(), "balance:", row.balance, "trust value:", row.trust_value)
    nonce_count += 1
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Hi Ake thanks for your answer. However it is throwing inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation in the following line of the code: encoded_input = encode_to_hex(row.id, row.trust_value)

Comment: Thank you Ake, there was some indentation issues and it is solved.